# Problems trying to count emojis in a dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

I have this code:

```
def split_count(text):

    emoji_list = []
    data = regex.findall(r'\X', text)
    for word in data:
        if any(char in emoji.UNICODE_EMOJI for char in word):
            emoji_list.append(word)

    return emoji_list
```

i tried this:

```
line = ["  me así, se  ds  hello ‍ emoji hello ‍‍‍ how are  you today"]

counter = split_count(line[0])
print(' '.join(emoji for emoji in counter))
```

And also returns empty.  What am i missing here?

To count emojis in a DataFrame. Although there are dozens of emojis in my df, my emoji_list returns empty.  Anyone knows why?

Using python 3.9 / linux Manjaro / JupyterNotebook / import emoji, re,  regex

Answer (score 0):

Try Changing emoji.UNICODE_EMOJI to emoji.UNICODE_EMOJI_ENGLISH..... rest of the code worked for meh.